# Winform position in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a weird issue. When I create a new Form in Visual Studio (WinForm), in the designer always appears at location 0,0.
Somehow (I don't know how), my form is positioned in the middle of the designer (the upper left corner is now in location 120, 150 for example).
Is there any way to put it back in 0,0? Tried to drag it but is not working.
Thanks in advance.
Fernando

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screen capture? And have you tried manually changing the Location property value to `0, 0` ?

Comment: @PaulSasik. There's the screen capture. The location property value is 0,0. Tried to delete the SUO file, but still the same. Thanks

Comment: What happens at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Add-ins? Some of them can cause weird things, even if they allegedly don't do anything with the designer.

Comment: @PaulSasik. At runtime is working fine.

Comment: @Joey. Tried. I'm using just one add-in. Even disabled is still happening. :(

Comment: The Location property at design time is set by a designer class.  Specifically the DocumentDesigner.Initialize() method.  You'd have this mishap if you changed the designer with an attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant. Never touched the designer with an attribute. Something happened when my Windows XP froze (I'd touched some keys) and then, when it came back, the form was missplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT! I was inheriting the form, and overriding the OnShown like this:

```
  private void gp_InicialN_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Rectangle oRect = Screen.GetBounds(this);
     this.Top = (oRect.Height / 2) - (this.Height / 2);
     this.Left = (oRect.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2);
  }
```

What I wasn't doing is checking the DesignMode variable. Now, once changed that works fine.

```
  private void gp_InicialN_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (!DesignMode)
     {
        Rectangle oRect = Screen.GetBounds(this);
        this.Top = (oRect.Height / 2) - (this.Height / 2);
        this.Left = (oRect.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2);
     }
  }
```